# How can I remove a list of divs from a parent div?

Tags: javascript, dom, parent, children

I have a problem with JavaScript.

I need to delete a list of divs from the parent div.
So i tried this:

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
if(divs != null)
{
    for(var v = 0; v < divs.length; v++)
    {
        parent.removeChild(divs[v]);
    }
}
```

But the problem is, that JS doesn't remove all of the divs. JS only removes the half of the list.

I also tried this:

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
if(divs != null)
{
    for(var v = 0; v < divs.length; v++)
    {
        parent.removeChild(divs[0]);
    }
}
```

But with the same results

Please help?

Comment: `parent` is the window object.. show us the complete code...

Comment: Are you sure all the divs found with `getElementsByTagName` are actual **children** of the parent div? And not possibly **descendents** of the parent? If they are descendents, I'm not sure the behavior of removing a descendent

Comment: The first should work fine. It will remove all `<div>` children of `parent`. Maybe you need to remove all nested `<div>` elements as well?

Comment: And I don't think `divs` will ever be `null`. The returned value from `getElementsByTagName` is a `HTMLCollection` - technically an array. So you would want to check for `.length > 0`, not `null`.

Comment: @ianpgall: Correct. The `null` check is pointless. `getElementsByTagName` will return an empty list if no elements are found. Plus the loop takes care of the case where the list is empty already.

Comment: @MattBurland Ahh yeah, good point about the loop anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

1: count down

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
if(divs != null)
{
    for(var v = divs.length - 1; v >= 0; v--)
    {
        parent.removeChild(divs[0]);
    }
}​
```

2: cache length:

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
if(divs != null)
{
    for(var v = 0, len = divs.length; v < len; v++)
    {
        parent.removeChild(divs[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if a div being found is a descendent, not a child. It will throw an exception. You can't just use `parent.removeChild` on any node - http://jsfiddle.net/ujaSv/ - notice how the actual child div is removed first, but an exception is thrown (in the browser's console) for the nested one.

Comment: That did the trick. I have this:
    for(var v = (divs.length -1); v >= 0; v--)
    {
        intervalSchema.removeChild(divs[v]);
    }

Answer (score 3):

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
while(divs[0]) {
    divs[0].parentNode.removeChild(divs[0])
}
```

The list returned by getElementsByTagName is *live*. This means it gets updated as you remove the DOM objects, so you length isn't the same on each cycle.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTcq9/1/).

Comment: +1 but `.length` on a live list does a recalculation, and is a bit expensive. I'd do this instead: `while(divs[0]) parent.removeChild(divs[0]);`

Comment: @user1689607: Fair enough. Good point. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see why. Each div may have a different parent. Can't tell from the question.

Comment: This won't work if a div being found is a descendent, not a child. It will throw an exception. You can't just use `parent.removeChild` on any node - http://jsfiddle.net/ujaSv/ - notice how the actual child div is removed first, but an exception is thrown (in the browser's console) for the nested one.

Comment: @MattBurland: The `div` may be a more deeply nested descendant of `parent`. `parent.removeChild` only works one level deep.

Comment: Yes it would be. `container.getElementsByTagName` returns a list of elements that are descendents of `container`. From the MDN docs ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName ) - "The subtree underneath the specified element is searched, excluding the element itself." It's not `getChildrenElementsByTagName`. Ever use `getElementsByTagName` on the `document`? It finds everything that matches

Comment: ...but the question does seem to imply that `parent` is the actual parent of the found `div` elements. If so in this exact case it would work.

Comment: @ianpgall: Fine, although there was no indication in the question that that was the case, I've fixed it.

Comment: @user1689607 True, it's implied, but it may not be understood that's how `removeChild` has to work. To me, `parent` means the "parent container". But using `getElementsByTagName` on it immediately after doesn't guarantee only **children** elements will be found. But of course, if the OP knows the HTML structure and can guarantee only actual children will be returned, then my point isn't relevant.

Comment: @ianpgall: Don't get me wrong. I'm just saying that the code make work in this instance, but even if it does, I think it would make sense to make it more robust by using `.parentNode`, or quite frankly, to make a reusable function that takes any collection *(live or not)* and removes the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try something like:

```
var divs = parent.getElementsByTagName("div");
if (divs.length > 0) {  // Technically unnecessary, as the for loop just won't run if there aren't any elements returned
    for (var v = divs.length; v >= 0; v--) {
        divs[v].parentNode.removeChild(divs[v]);
    }
}
```

As an explanation of why this is correct, the use of `removeChild` must be used to remove an actual **child** of the parent node. If `div[v]` is a descendent (you know, like nested inside of another element - not a div - that is an actual child of `parent`). This is the safe way to remove an element when you have a reference to it. You guarantee the parent node of the element is removing it, and therefore is valid. If you check your console for trying to use `parent.removeChild` like yours and others code, there is an exception thrown for any descendent - http://jsfiddle.net/ujaSv/

Although it's important to point out that a better alternative to a for loop for this is:

```
while (divs[0]) {
    divs[0].parentNode.removeChild(divs[0]);
}
```

I did not think of this brilliance - this was decided in another answer/comment area.